# How to pass the value of a variable to an argument of a function in Macro SAS?

Tags: loops, macros, sas

```
ID   a1 a2 a3 a4    _1 _2 _3 _4 _5 _6 _7 _8 _9
1    _1 _3 _6 _9     8  5  9  8  6 10  2  1  4
2    _2 _5 _8 _9    10  6  2  7 10  8  3  5  9
3    _1 _2 _4 _8     3  6  1  9  6  9  3  0  4
...     ...                ...
```

Here a1-a4 show the column numbers, which are corresponding to the variable name _1-_9.I want to create three variables v1, v2, v3, where

```
For ID=1,  v1=sum(of _1-_3), v2=sum(of _3-_6),v3=sum(of _6-_9);
For ID=2,  v1=sum(of _2-_5), v2=sum(of _5-_8),v3=sum(of _8-_9);
For ID=3,  v1=sum(of _1-_2), v2=sum(of _2-_4),v3=sum(of _4-_8);
....       ...
```

For example, for ID=1, v1=8+5+9=22, v2=9+8+6+10=33.
Here is my code:

```
%Macro sumup;
    data test; set test;
        %do n=1 %to 3;
            v&n=sum (of a&n-a%eval(&n+1)); 
        %end;
    run;
%mend;
%sumup;
```

The problem is that a&n and a%eval(&n+1) are treated as variable name. But I want to treat their values as variable name. I know in call execute we can use '||a&n||'. But how about in macro? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it directly like that; SAS needs to know how to compile the instructions prior to it knowing what the actual values are.  You can, however, do this with arrays.

```
data want; 
  set test;
   array nums _1-_9;
   array as a1-a4;
   array vs v1-v3;
   do n=1 to 3;
     do i = as[n] to as[n+1];
       vs[n] = sum(vs[n],nums[i]);
     end;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: There is a typo: v[_n] should be vs[_n]. When I ran your code, an error shows in the log. ERROR: Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the BY expression is missing, zero, or invalid.

Comment: That implies that as[n] or as[n+1] does not exist or is missing.

Comment: Actually it's because they are inputted as strings. After converting them into numeric values, your code works! Thank you!